# Load a page within another one, using PHP

Tags: php, apache

So, I have a php page, in which there is "simple" script, that decides whether it should load page one or page two, depending on whether or not is the user logged in. Is it possible to do that, without the need to redirect to another page?

*I'm a begginer in PHP, and I'd probably use Python instead, if my webhosting supported it.*

Comment: This is far too broad. You don't tell us how you determine if someone is logged in or not. You also don't tell us how you serve your pages.

Comment: @Keeleon a function returns true or false depending on whether user is not logged in. Just like kainaw anticipated within his answer. And I don't fully understand the "how you server webpages" part to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your main page is called "index.php" and you have two HTML pages "loggedin.inc" and "notloggedin.inc". Why .inc? So you can block people from accessing .inc files directly in your .htaccess file.

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in()) include('loggedin.inc');
else include('notloggedin.inc');
?>
```

There are literally hundreds of ways to do this. Just pick one that makes you happy. I like doing it this way.

Comment: So you're saying that include function loads said page?

Comment: Include will pass the file to the user. It doesn't reload or redirect. It just passes the file through the PHP parser and to the end user.

Comment: Thanks, setting as solution.